# Process is not defined in dependency package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

Recently i had to create a new project in react using typescript / webpack. I have included the package "sass-loader" which has a dependency of chalk (1.1.3).

When I try to npm start, the console shows this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/chalk/index.js (main.js:62661)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:228732)
    at fn (main.js:228970)
    at Object../node_modules/@babel/highlight/lib/index.js (main.js:403)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:228732)
    at fn (main.js:228970)
    at Object../node_modules/@babel/code-frame/lib/index.js (main.js:19)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:228732)
    at fn (main.js:228970)
    at Object../node_modules/parse-json/index.js (main.js:120631)
```

I don't know if this could be a problem with this package or maybe is my webpack configuration... I'm new in webpack.

Here is my webpack conf:

```
{
  mode: "development",
  output: {
    publicPath: "/",
  },
  entry: "./src/index.tsx",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/i,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react",
              "@babel/preset-typescript",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          { 
            loader: 'css-loader', 
            options: { 
              modules: { 
                localIdentName: 'styles_[local]_[hash:base64:5]' 
              }
            },
          },
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader",
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          { 
            loader: 'css-loader', 
            options: { 
              modules: { 
                localIdentName: 'styles_[local]_[hash:base64:5]' 
              }
            },
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".jsx"],
    alias: {
      '@': '/src',
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "public/index.html",
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin({
      async: false,
    }),
    new ESLintPlugin({
      extensions: ["js", "jsx", "ts", "tsx"],
    })
  ],
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "build"),
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 4000,
    open: false,
    hot: true,
    stats: 'errors-only'
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance.